# How to evaluate inverse Laplace transform of $e^{- \sqrt{s}} $ using series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form-expressions, gamma-function, laplace-transform

I tried to find an inverse Laplace transform by series as follows
$$ f(t)=L^{-1}_s\left(e^{-\sqrt{s}}\right)(t)=L^{-1}_s\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!} s^{\frac{k}{2}}\right)(t)$$
and by separate even orders with odd orders and get
$$ f(t)=L^{-1}_s\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{2k}}{(2k)!} s^{k}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} s^{k+\frac{1}{2}}\right)(t)$$
then
$$ f(t)=L^{-1}_s\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{s^k}{(2k)!}\right)-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+1)!} \frac{1}{\Gamma\left(-k-\frac{1}{2}\right)t^{k+\frac{3}{2}}} $$
now its easy to evaluate the series
$$ f(t)=L^{-1}_s\left(\cosh\left(\sqrt{s}\right)\right)+\frac{t^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{2\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{4t}} $$
now I know the result is only $$\frac{t^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{2\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{4t}} $$ So is the  Laplace transform of $\cosh\left(\sqrt{s}\right)$ is zero ? and what if we use this way
$$ L^{-1}_s\left(\cosh\left(\sqrt{s}\right)\right)=L^{-1}_s\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{s^k}{(2k)!}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k)!\Gamma(-k)t^{k+1}} $$
now gamma for negative integers is infinity So we can say (as wolfram say)
$$ \frac{1}{\Gamma(-k)}=0$$
finally
$$ f(t)=L^{-1}_s\left(e^{-\sqrt{s}}\right)(t)=\frac{t^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{2\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{4t}} $$
So is that using of series to get the result of inverse Laplace transform wrong ? or its true just here and how ?

**THIS QUESTION asked also on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4849993/how-to-evaluate-inverse-laplace-transform-of-e-sqrts-using-series)**

Comment: @Nemo I know the result and I just asking about using series is it correct way always ? and how the inverse transform of cosh function is zero ?

Comment: Perhaps $\cosh\left(\sqrt{s}\right)=\frac{e^{-\sqrt{s}}}{2}+\frac{e^{\sqrt{s}}}{2}$ provides some insight. The first term $\frac{e^{-\sqrt{s}}}{2}$ leads back to the original problem, but how would you evaluate the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{e^{\sqrt{s}}}{2}$ where $e^{\sqrt{s}}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} s^{k/2}$?

Answer (score 6):

Let me first look at a simpler example, instead of the square root consider the inverse Laplace transform of $e^{-s}$. If you write the series expansion and invert term by term you obtain
$$L^{-1}_s\left(e^{-{s}}\right)(t)=L^{-1}_s\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!} s^k\right)(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k t^{-k-1}}{k! \Gamma (-k)}=0.$$
The correct answer is
$$L^{-1}_s\left(e^{-{s}}\right)(t)=\delta(t-1),$$
so you miss the delta function.

---

A similar contribution is missed in the square root case from the OP. The inverse Laplace transform of $\cosh\sqrt{s}$ is not zero but a series of derivatives of delta functions,
$$L^{-1}_s\left(\cosh\left(\sqrt{s}\right)\right)=L^{-1}_s\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{s^k}{(2k)!}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2k!}\frac{d^k}{dt^k}\delta(t).$$

Comment: ok and now what about my example ? should I add delta function for the inverse Laplace transform of $e^{-\sqrt{s}}$ ? I think using series like this way is correct but need some conditions .

Comment: yes, the inverse Laplace transform of $\cosh\sqrt{s}$ contains delta functions $\delta(t)$ and derivatives, so you can set it to zero for $t>0$.